Project 3D vector onto 2D plane
Consider two vectors (or quaternions) in 3D space.
Consider a plane normal to one of the vectors.
How do I calculate projection of the second vector onto the plane?
By projection I mean 2D vector on the plane in coordinates of that plane.

When one vector is projected onto another, it can be separated into two components:
Parallel Component: This is the part of the vector that lies along the direction of the other vector. It represents how much of the first vector aligns with the second.
Perpendicular Component: This is the part of the vector that is orthogonal (at a 90° angle) to the other vector. It represents how much of the first vector deviates from the second.
The parallel component is given by:
Pa = (a.b) * b/(b.b);

The perpendicular component is:
Pe = a - Pa;

Here "." is a dot product.
